# Loading Dynamic Cascadding Dropdown In JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am creating a category form, where I want to load dropdown list to be dynamic. After changing of the dropdown, I want to load all the child elements into a new dropdown, similarly, if it has no children it will load a new text box which allows creating a new one.

Here's my code 
**HTML**

```
<div id="categoryContainer" data-target="@Url.Action("GetCategoryJsonList","Master", new { parentId="parentIdVal"})">
            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.BootHzLabelFor(x => x.Category, new { @class = "" })
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @if (Model?.CategoryList != null && Model?.CategoryList.Count > 0)
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control f" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "" } }, new { @class = "form-control f" })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        loadCategories();
        $("#Name").focus();



        function onchangeCategory() {
            const propertyName = 'ParentId';
            var category = $('#ParentId, #ParentId-temp');
            category.on('change', function (d) {
                var thisOp = this;
                var sValue = this.value;
                var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group');
                var parentContainer = $(this).parents('#parentsContainer');
                var callUrl = parentContainer.data('target');
                callUrl = callUrl.replace('parentIdVal', sValue);
                var nextItems = $(this).parents('.form-group').nextAll('.form-group');
                var previousItem = $(this).parents('.form-group').prev('.form-group');
                var prevOption = $(previousItem).find('select');
                if (sValue !== "0") {
                    $(prevOption[0]).attr('id', propertyName + "-temp");
                    $(thisOp).attr('id', propertyName);

                    $.get(callUrl, function (resData) {
                        if (resData.length > 1) {
                            var options = "";
                            $.each(resData, function (i, d) {
                                var data = $(this);
                                options += "<option value=" + $(this)[0].Key + ">" + $(this)[0].Value + "</option>";
                            });
                            var itemClone = null;
                            itemClone = parent.clone(); //create clone of the current item
                            itemClone.find('select').html('');
                            itemClone.find('select').html(options);

                            parentContainer.append(itemClone);
                            onchangeCategory();
                        } else {
                            $(prevOption[0]).attr('id', propertyName + "-temp");
                            $(thisOp).attr('id', propertyName);
                            $(nextItems).remove();
                            onchangeCategory = function () { };
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $(prevOption[0]).attr('id', propertyName + "-temp");
                    $(thisOp).attr('id', propertyName);
                    $(nextItems).remove();
                    onchangeCategory = function () { };
                }
            });
        }
        onchangeCategory();

    });
```

This code working properly if I am commenting the altering ID attribute else it's creating 3/4 times for extra list `see image`

```
SEE VIDEO LINK
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pKqsjnSd1SbquGXG5Oal1kyBzK7i-bC2

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGjlk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems, you called onchangeCategory() many times. I did this on my project like below, hope that helps you :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select#Bank").change(function () {
            var e = document.getElementById("Bank");
            var selectedObj = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            var procemessage = "<option value='0'>select</option>";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Base/GetBranchesforBank",
                data: { parentId: selectedObj },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var markup = "<option value='0'>select</option>";
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("select#branch").html(markup).show();
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert("error : " + reponse);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: yeah, you are right I am calling it many times, beacuse when I append a new element then that's element event need to bind, else it will not append the child of it self, Eg, Stationary>{BOOKS, PAPER, PENCIL[ isSelected]}>{COLORPENCIL, WATERCOLORPENCIL}>{load-childs}

Comment: putting onchange on   $(document).ready(function () { } will fire it automatically on every change, there is no need for handling like that,

Comment: if you don't mind. can see the link I recorded the issue

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pKqsjnSd1SbquGXG5Oal1kyBzK7i-bC2

Comment: when you append HTML to a tag it will be there till you remove it, you just hide it, remove that appended HTML then append new one

Comment: you have remove method just in else parts if we had data and we had extra HTML appended before, they should be removed. in this part : if (resData.length > 1) {}